# Samsung Galaxy Note stopped vibrating

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note, vibration

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 1 and it has quit vibrating. All the options for it are turned on but it has quit working. What do I do?

Comment: Please edit your post as it is not clear what are you asking, it will be good to edit it and elaborate to help you by others. If you will not do so I'm pretty sure it will be closed soon as "Its not clear what are you asking?"

Comment: What do you think may have caused this? Did you install any app , or change a setting somewhere?